# Dispose Explicitly Called on SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web // SPDisposeCheck error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spdisposechecker, memory-leak

I have used SPDisposeCheck command line utility on following code and it gives comments as

> "Dispose Explicitly Called on SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web".

I carefully analyse my code for any potential memory leaks but I don't find any issue and I properly called Dispose method. This is the code which I think handled properly for any memory leak:

```
private static void MyWebParts(SPListItem sourceItem, SPListItem destinationItem, bool somevariable)
        {


            SPLimitedWebPartManager sourceWP = sourceItem.File.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
            SPLimitedWebPartManager destinationWP = destinationItem.File.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);

            try
            {
                Method1(destinationItem, destinationWP, sourceWP);
                Method2(sourceItem, destinationItem);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                SPContextManager.Current.LogManager.LogErrorToDevelopers(err);
            }
            finally
            {
                destinationWP.Dispose();
                sourceWP.Dispose();
            }
```

I have dispose the `SPLimitedWebPartManager` Objects and it seems there is no memory leaks, but SPDIsposeCheck command line tool gives this comments:

> 1. Dispose Explicitly Called on SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web    sourceWP.{Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager}Dispose()
> 2. Dispose Explicitly Called on SPLimitedWebPartManager.Web    destinationWP.{Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager}Dispose()

Why is that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, I'm quite sure your code is good; this is most probably a false positive from SPDisposeCheck.
As Stefan Goßner states [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2010/12/13/new-version-of-spdisposecheck-has-been-released/) false positives can definitely happen. And another one [here](https://www.spcaf.com/blog/stop-using-spdisposecheck-or-msocaf-with-sharepoint-2013-now/).
And [here](http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/spdisposecheck-how-to-suppress-a-false-positive/) Anita explains how to suppress these false positives if the bother you.